# Add captcha validation to my custom form for Frontend posting

Tags: javascript, forms, captcha

i have implemented the frontend form, which enables UNREGISTERED users to post on my site.

Everything in working perfectly, the only problem I have is with the implementation of the captcha.

All of the captcha solutions I found needs to put some outer file in the form action. But my form has this syntax:

```
<form action="">
```

I do not know what to do? If I put the file in the action field, I cannot add the post anymore. How would I put the verification code for the captcha in the same file as the form is? Or any better solution?

EDIT:
How can I modify the form, that it would do the same thing (add post) as it does it now, but that I could include some file in the form action:

```
<form action="some.php">
```

Comment: This is not WordPress related. Search for it in [se].

Comment: I'm running this code on wordpress but I agree, after all it is more PHP oriented, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Really Simple Captcha WodPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-captcha/). Here is a "how to" for implementing Really Simple Captcha for custom plugins: http://www.lost-in-code.com/platforms/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-using-really-simple-captcha/

Comment: hm, I cannot get it working! Damn... maybe because I have this wp_nounce fields? Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aqMA7/

Comment: I use Really Simple Captcha for pretty much all my forms, it's surprisingly easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and first send the form content, here the captcha, to your file where the captcha is checked. Then send the form data to your posting routine.

```
$( '#frontend-post-form-submit' ).click(
  function(event) {
    var data = { ... insert the captcha from the form here ... };
    $.post(
      'some_file.php',
      data,
      function( result ) {
        // stop if the captcha isn't correct
        if ( false === result.result ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }

        return result.result;
       }
     );
  }
);
```

If your submit button have the id `frontend-post-form-submit` and the captcha isn't correct, the jQuery will stop sending the form (`event.preventDefault`). Else the form will be submitted normally.